# Simple MYSQL count, group by, not working using Pentaho Report Designer CE

Tags: mysql, sql, count, pentaho

I need to write a query which will pull from two different tables, count the results and return to me in one row, the total results.

I've come across a few problems. When I run the query **without** a count expression, I am returned 645 rows. 645 is the correct number, I want to be returned 1 row displaying the total as "645".

When I use a count expression, it counts the total number of rows in **one** table and not both, so with a count expression, I am returned with 761 (which is the total rows without clauses taking effect).

```
SELECT
     `cuesheet_tx_dates`.`txdate`,
     `cuesheet_tx_dates`.`trans_station`,
     `cuesheets`.`status`,
     count(`cuesheet_tx_dates`.`txdate`)
FROM
     `cuesheet_tx_dates` INNER JOIN `cuesheets` ON `cuesheet_tx_dates`.`cuesheets_id` = `cuesheets`.`id`
WHERE
     `cuesheet_tx_dates`.`txdate` BETWEEN "15-01-01"AND "15-01-31"
 AND `cuesheet_tx_dates`.`trans_station` = "HIS"
HAVING
     `cuesheets`.`status` = "C"
```

If I use Group By, the query will not run with the Having clause. I don't know why, it just refuses to run. This will display me with 2 rows, 1 displaying 645 and the other displaying 116 (116 + 645 = 761). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm new to MYSQL, no training, no supervision, no team for help just the internet so please excuse any stupid things I've said or done

Comment: So we have some idea of what the query should *not* be doing.  Can you provide sample data and desired results to explain what it *should be* doing?

Comment: I didn't understand very well what you wanna get from the query, but if you wanna use group by, you should put it before the having clause in order to work. Ex: GROUP BY <field> HAVING <field2>= <value>

Comment: Simon, putting the Group By before the having clause sorted it. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a query that returns one result and does filtering, then I am expecting something like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM cuesheet_tx_dates td INNER JOIN
     cuesheets s
     ON td.cuesheets_id = s.id
WHERE td.txdate BETWEEN '2015-01-01' and '2014-01-31' AND 
      td.trans_station = 'HIS' AND
      s.status = 'C';
```

The changes that I made are mostly for readability:

- Shorter table aliases.
- String delimiter of `'` rather than `"` (the first is the ANSI standard)
- Removing the `HAVING` clause, which is almost never used on an aggregation query with no `group by`.
- Using ISO standard formats for the date constants.

Answer (score 0):

...or if you want the grouping data to be shown as well

```
SELECT cuesheet_tx_dates.txdate,
       cuesheet_tx_dates.trans_station,
       cuesheets.status,
       count(*) AS number_of_records
FROM cuesheet_tx_dates td INNER JOIN
     cuesheets s
     ON td.cuesheets_id = s.id
WHERE td.txdate BETWEEN '2015-01-01' and '2014-01-31' AND 
      td.trans_station = 'HIS' AND
      s.status = 'C'
GROUP BY cuesheet_tx_dates.txdate,
         cuesheet_tx_dates.trans_station,
         cuesheets.status;
```